# Manage Locale in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, locale, android-jetpack-compose

How do I manage the locale with android **Jetpack Compose**. How do compose find the locale to set in the view.

Answer (score 12):

`androidx.compose.ui.text.intl.Locale` exists, and if it fulfills your needs that is great, you can use `Locale.current` however very often you want a java.util.Locale instead.

To do that, I suggest a function like this

```kotlin
@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun getLocale(): Locale? {
  val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
  return ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(configuration).get(0)
}
```

Or if you want do default to whatever `Locale.getDefault()` returns and not null, you can adjust it to this:

```kotlin
@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun getLocale(): Locale {
  val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
  return ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(configuration).get(0) ?: LocaleListCompat.getDefault()[0]!!
}
```

It's important to use `LocalConfiguration.current` so that if there is a configuration change, the function will recompose and you will get the latest Locale instead of a stale one. I've recently had [this discussion](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/8453168/there-doesn-t-seem-to-exist-a-compositionlocal-for-locale-in) where this was mentioned.

`ConfigurationCompat.getLocales` makes sure that it works on all API versions. If you are on API >= 24 anyway, go ahead and use `LocalConfiguration.current.locales` directly.

Bonus: This also works perfectly when using the [per-app language APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages), since it returns whatever language was chosen in the app language settings.

Comment: Btw, Compose's `Locale.current` is not state-aware: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240191036

Comment: Yes, I mention this in the section of the answer that says "It's important to use LocalConfiguration.current so that if there is a configuration change, the function will recompose and you will get the latest Locale instead of a stale one"

Comment: why use `LocalConfiguration` instead of `LocalContext`? `context.resources.configuration.locales`

Comment: Why use LocalContext when you can use LocalConfiguration?

Here https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt;l=94-118?q=%22LocalConfiguration%20provides%22 is the code which shows that configuration is provided in a way that you will be getting the correct one even after config changes.

Answer (score 4):

To access the Locale from a Composable, use this:

```
Locale.current
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/intl/Locale#current()

Comment: it's different object, doesn't have display language properties and so on